# Reading multiple CSV files from Specified Unix directory

Tags: scripting

We are passing file name as input to script i.e. $1. And we are removing the new line characters from a column using awk. Now, my requirement is instead of passing file name as input, the script should read all the files from a specified directory and remove the new line characters from each file one by one loop wise.

Sample script:

```
awk -v RS='\r' 'NR>1{print prev} {sub(/^\n/,""); gsub(/\n/," "); prev=$0}' $1 > temp_file.CSV
mv temp_file.CSV $1
chmod 777 $1
```

Can you please help on the same.

Comment: Welcome, can you share with us example names of the files? [edit] the question, don't add it in the comments. Use the format `{}` tool.

Comment: don't you just need `dos2unix multiple*.csv`? also with that your awk commmad you lose the last line of the input file in the output.

Comment: Using `tr -d '\n'` would be more efficient for removing all newline characters, if that is really what you want to do (it's a bit unclear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a `for` loop?

```
for f in /somepath/myfile_*.csv
do
    awk -f myscript.awk "$f"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Also in my directory I have files with .CSV and .gz extension. how can i handle both of of them in for loop. my_file_*.csv and my_file_*.gz . Can i use or in for loop. Also if i need to unzip the files how can i handle it. Thanks again. Really appreciate the help

Comment: @mansibajaj We don't really welcome follow-up questions in the comments. If you want to have further help, then consider asking a new question. Remember to give full context for your issue, examples of your files, what you want to do, and what happens when you try.